# Rails 4.0 undefined method `call'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails app whereby I'm creating a highcharts line graph to compare stocks in 2 industries, Telecommunication and Agriculture while following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts), ryan bates highstocks video.

The graph will be output in a view, index.html.erb of stock_quotes whereby the javascipt code for highcharts is as follows:

```
<div id="quotes_chart", style="width=560px; height:300px;">

  $(function(){   
  new HighCharts.Chart( 
  chart: {
    renderTo: "quotes_chart"
  },
  title: {
   text: "Daily trades" 
  },
  xAxis: {
   type: "datetime"
  },
  yAxis: {
   title: {
     text: "Shillings"
  }
},
tooltip: {
  formatter: function(){
    return HighCharts.dateFormat("%B %e, %Y", this.x) + ': ' + "Kshs" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
  }
},
series: [
<% { "Telecommunication" => StockQuote.telecomm, "Agriculture" => StockQuote.agric }.each do |name, prices|
%>
{
  name: <%= name %>
  pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
  pointStart: <%= 2.weeks.ago.to_i * 1000 %>,
  data: <%= (2.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| StockQuote.price_on(date).to_f}.inspect%>
},
<% end %>]
  }); 
}); 
 </div>
```

The model **stock_quote.rb** is as follows:

```
scope :agric, where(category: "Agriculture")
scope :telecomm, where(category: "Telecommunication")

def self.price_on(date)
  where("date(published_at) = ?", date).sum(:total_price)
end
```

This is what is being output on the stock_quotes div:

```
$(function(){ new HighCharts.Chart( chart: { renderTo: "quotes_chart" }, title: { text: "Daily trades" }, xAxis: { type: "datetime" }, yAxis: { title: { text: "Shillings" } }, tooltip: { formatter: function(){ return HighCharts.dateFormat("%B %e, %Y", this.x) + ': ' + "Kshs" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2); } }, series: [ { name: Telecommunication pointInterval: 86400000, pointStart: 1398157330000, data: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 554.0] }, { name: Agriculture pointInterval: 86400000, pointStart: 1398157330000, data: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 554.0] }, ] }); });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look [rails 4 scope syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412719/rails-4-scope-with-argument/23412746#23412746)
instead:

```
  scope :agric, where(category: "Agriculture")
  scope :telecomm, where(category: "Telecommunication")
```

use:

```
  scope :agric, -> { where(category: "Agriculture") }
  scope :telecomm, -> { where(category: "Telecommunication") }
```

Comment: every day the same questions.

Comment: Solved the syntax error, but check my comment on Holger Just's answer below

Comment: The div was closed its only I had not included it, I've edited the code though

Comment: My first assumption is that I had not installed jquery-rails gem properly, but I then went ahead and reinstalled it in my app follwoing [this](http://buddylindsey.com/add-jquery-to-ruby-on-rails/) blog and it still doesn't show anything

Comment: try [highcharts gem](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/highcharts-rails) for rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

Your scope definitions must be with a proc object, not a plain where statement. This is because they need to be evaluated during the actual query of the scope, not during the initial setup of the class. As such, please use this in your model:

```
scope :agric, -> { where(category: "Agriculture") }
scope :telecomm, -> { where(category: "Telecommunication") }
```

Comment: Yeah...I did that and there is no error, However instead of my javascript graph being output, I'm getting my javascript code being shown on that div.