# Scope parameter as array in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, scope, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this scope with the parameter city, the scope receives the parameter, joins a table call Restaurant (because I have the param there) and then it makes a where condition with IN for multiple OR.

```
scope :by_cities, -> (city) { joins(:restaurant).where('restaurants.city IN (?)', city) }
```

The thing is that I want to learn how the scope can receive an array of param in the scope, I already have tried a lot of stuff and I'm taking the guide of this guy: [Rails 4 scope with argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412719/rails-4-scope-with-argument) and this: [ActiveRecord where field = ? array of possible values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954500/activerecord-where-field-array-of-possible-values)

> Logs

`Parameters: {"city"=>"SanPedro"}
   SELECT "vacancies".* FROM "vacancies" INNER JOIN "restaurants" ON 
   "restaurants"."id" = "vacancies"."restaurant_id" WHERE (restaurants.city 
   IN ('SanPedro'))`

> Route

`http://localhost:3000/v1/vacancies?city=SanPedro&Monterrey`

But, don't understand very well how to do it, anyone knows about this?

Comment: "don't understand very well how to do it" - but you already did it. Use it like this: `MyModel.by_cities([city1, city2])`

Comment: doesn't work that way, I already tried, when I write `MyModel.by_cities('New York', 'San Fransisco')` I get this error:

`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)`

Comment: Have you tried `scope :by_cities, -> (*cities) { joins(:restaurant).where('restaurants.city IN (?)', cities) }`? BTW, the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) state *"Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."*

Comment: I already try that too, fortunately, I don't get an error but when I'm getting the consult in the database I don't get all the info, only one city, the return of the logs was this:
`SELECT "vacancies".* FROM "vacancies" INNER JOIN "restaurants" ON "restaurants"."id" = "vacancies"."restaurant_id" WHERE (restaurants.city IN ('Monterrey'))` and I want the same but with multiple values, like this: `SELECT "vacancies".* FROM "vacancies" INNER JOIN "restaurants" ON "restaurants"."id" = "vacancies"."restaurant_id" WHERE (restaurants.city IN ('Monterrey, SanPedro'))`

Comment: I update the info @jvillian

Comment: "when I write `MyModel.by_cities('New York', 'San Fransisco')`" - but that's not what i wrote. My example has an array, yours doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimally, there is a problem with how you're forming your url query, here:

```
http://localhost:3000/v1/vacancies?city=SanPedro&Monterrey
```

As you can see in your params:

```
Parameters: {"city"=>"SanPedro"}
```

Your not getting an array of cities. Try something more like:

```
http://localhost:3000/v1/vacancies?city%5B%5D=San+Pedro&city%5B%5D=Monterrey
```

Which should give you something like:

```
Parameters: {"city"=>['San Pedro', 'Monterrey']}
```

BTW, you can see how a proper query string should look by doing:

```
{city: ['San Pedro', 'Monterrey']}.to_query
```

in your console.

Then, you should be able to do something like:

```
Vacancy.by_city(params[:city])
```

Comment: thank you for your response, it helps me, I didn't know about `to_query`, it will help me a lot in the future!